# JAVA 8 - Stream features giving error while retriving data from 3 POJO class

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am having 3 POJO class for `products`, `attribute` & `value`. All three POJOs are have relationship with other POJO class. Now, I want to retrive value for the
    each and every products.

It was working perfectly with the older approach but now i want to modify my code with new JAVA 8 features.

Please find my code below.

```
listProducts.stream().forEachOrdered(listproducts -> 
listproducts.getProductAttr()
                .stream().forEachOrdered(attr -> 
(((Collection<ProductAttrValue>) attr.getProductAttrValue()
                .stream().filter(attrlabel -> 
attrlabel.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("source"))))
                .stream().forEachOrdered(attrval ->
                                {
                                    System.out.println(attrval.getValue());
                                }
                            )       
                        )

            );
```

Please find the error message that I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
at Hibernate.Testing.App.lambda$1(App.java:81)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown 
Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(Unknown Source)
at Hibernate.Testing.App.lambda$0(App.java:81)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(Unknown Source)
at Hibernate.Testing.App.main(App.java:80)
```

If am not doing type casting `.stream().forEachOrdered(attr -> ((Collection<ProductAttrValue>) attr.getProductAttrValue()` am getting the below errors.

[image]
Please find my Product POJO class

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private long std_delivery_Time;
    private int min_order_Quantity;

    private String status;
    private long catalog_Id;
    private Date expiration_Date;
    private int rank;
    private String product_Type;
    private int is_Visible;
    private String product_Group;
       private String code;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
          this.id = id;
         }


    public String getCode() {
      return code;
     }


    public void setCode(String code) {
      this.code = code;
     }

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductAttr> productAttr;
    public List<ProductAttr> getProductAttr() {
        return productAttr;
    }

    public void setProductAttr(List<ProductAttr> productAttr) {
        this.productAttr = productAttr;
    }
 }
```

ProductAttr class

```
public class ProductAttr {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private long product_id;


    public ProductAttr() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(long product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID",  referencedColumnName = "ID", 
insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "productAttr", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProductAttrValue> productAttrValue;

        public Set<ProductAttrValue> getProductAttrValue() {
            return productAttrValue;
        }

        public void setProductAttrValue(Set<ProductAttrValue> 
productAttrValue) {
            this.productAttrValue = productAttrValue;
        }

}
```

ProductValue class

```
public class ProductAttrValue {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ATTR_ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private long attr_id;

    @Column(name = "LABEL")
    private String label;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value; 

        public long getAttr_id() {
            return attr_id;
        }

        public void setAttr_id(long attr_id) {
            this.attr_id = attr_id;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }


      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "ATTR_ID",  referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable 
      = false, updatable = false)

      private ProductAttr productAttr;

      public ProductAttr getProductAttr() {
            return productAttr;
      }

      public void setProductAttr(ProductAttr productAttr) {
            this.productAttr = productAttr;
        }

      public ProductAttrValue() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


}
```

Comment: `(((Collection<ProductAttrValue>) attr.getProductAttrValue()` why do you need that cast?

Comment: Otherwise am getting the error message on the last  `.stream()`. Please find the attached screenshot.

Comment: Need more information in order to help. What are the contents of the `listProducts` ? What is the implementation of `ProductAttrValue` ?

Comment: A stream is not a collection. casting a stream to a collection won't magically makes it a collection.

Comment: @IshanThilinaSomasiri - added all the 3 pojo classes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indentation suggests a wrong mindset. These `stream()` operation are not on the same level. You have a nested operation:

```
listProducts.stream().forEachOrdered(listproducts -> 
    listproducts.getProductAttr().stream().forEachOrdered(attr -> 
        attr.getProductAttrValue().stream()
                                  .filter(av -> av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("source"))
                     /*.stream()*/.forEachOrdered(av -> System.out.println(av.getValue()))
    )
);
```

(I changed the misleading name `attrlabel` and `attrval` to `av`, as these aren’t labels or values; you’re invoking `.getLabel()` and `.getValue()` *subsequently* on these variables, so I used `av` for “`ProductAttrValue`”)

The `filter` operation is the only operation that is *not* nesting, as it is an intermediate operation chained to the stream and the terminal operation just has to be chained to the resulting stream. There is no `stream()` invocation necessary at that place (the one marked with `/*.stream()*/`).

That said, you should avoid such nested operation.

You can use

```
listProducts.stream()
            .flatMap(listproducts -> listproducts.getProductAttr().stream())
            .flatMap(attr -> attr.getProductAttrValue().stream())
            .filter(av -> av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("source"))
            .forEachOrdered(av -> System.out.println(av.getValue()));
```

instead.

Comment: How to add multiple filters `.filter()` in this.? and print the same...

Comment: You can insert `filter` steps  into this chain wherever you like, depending on which objects you want to filter, directly after `stream()`, if you want to filter `Product`s, after the first `flatMap(…)` to filter `ProductAttr`s or after the second `flatMap(…)` to filter `ProductAttrValue`s, as has already been done, but you may insert more, as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

All stream methods return another stream. To convert back to a list you need to use a Collector:

```
<your stream>.collect(Collectors.toList());
```